# CSV file doesn't open using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
#Directory change
import os
os.chdir('D:\\Scripts\\Visual Studio Code\\money_outflow')
print('Current directory:', os.getcwd())

#Importing pandas as pd
import pandas as pd 

#Reading account.csv
accountData = pd.read_csv("account.csv")
accountData.head()

#User input
date = input('Enter today''s date: ')
amount = float(input('Enter the amount: '))

#Appending input
user_input = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [date],
                           'Amount Spent': [amount]})
accountData.append(user_input, ignore_index=True)
```

Hi! I have tried to run this code on a file that has data in it.
However, the command 'accountData.head()' doesn't render anything.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried `print(accountData.head())` ?

Comment: What happens if you type print(accountData)?

Comment: How do you know? `accountData.head()` gets the head but since you don't assign it to anything, silently discards. If you are running in jupyter or the python shell or something, you'd see something. But as a vanilla python script `print(accountData.head())` will be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a print statement

`print(accountData.head())`

Answer (score 0):

Use the display command to see the output.
Therefore, use:

```
display (accountData.head())
```

and

```
display(accountData.append(user_input, ignore_index=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by csv bro (get data from first row):

```
import csv
data = []
with open('wss/wss.csv', "r") as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
    for row in csvReader:
        data.append(row[0])
print (data[1])
print (data[2])
```

For me csv is easier ;)

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks! <3